# CAShapeLayer and CABasicAnimation for circle - loader style - blinking

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I'm having fun with `CAShapeLayer` on a playground project.

I want to create an animation coloring the stroke of a `CALayer` in a clock way, then, an animation removing the stroke color, in the same direction. So it gives the effect to putting and removing the strokes.

So far, it looks pretty much like what in wanted except, just before calling `fullAnimate` after the second time, the stroke blink like it was "full" ,then it disappears, then the animation plays again.

I agree my code ain't the best so far since I'm just playing with it yet, but I've look for explanation and did not found any usefull answer.

Can someone explain to me what's happening there ? and how to avoid it ?

here is my playground file

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

enum CircleProgressionViewAnimationState {
    case start, firstAnimation, secondAnimation, progress, stop
}

class CircleProgressionView : UIView {
    static let offset: CGFloat = 10.0
    private var path : UIBezierPath? {
        didSet {
            circleLayer.path = path?.cgPath
        }
    }

    private var state : CircleProgressionViewAnimationState {
        didSet {
            observe(change: state)
        }
    }
    private var progressionPath : UIBezierPath?
    var circleLayerContainer = CALayer()

    var circleLayer : CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)

        return shapeLayer
    }()

    var circleProgressLayer : CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        shapeLayer.cornerRadius = 2
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
        shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        state = .stop
        super.init(frame:frame)
        initLayerValues()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        state = .stop
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        initLayerValues()
    }



    private func initLayerValues() {
        let side = min(frame.width, frame.height)
        circleLayerContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: side, height: side)
        let offset = CircleProgressionView.offset
        let bezierSide = side - (offset * 2)
        let bezierRect = CGRect(x:offset,
                                y:offset,
                                width: bezierSide,
                                height:bezierSide)
        path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bezierRect,
                            cornerRadius: CGFloat(bezierSide / 2))
        circleLayerContainer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(circleLayerContainer)
        layer.addSublayer(circleProgressLayer)
    }

    func setProgressionPath(_ progressionInPercent: CGFloat) {
        let progression = progressionInPercent / 100 * (360)
        let rad = (progression + 270) * CGFloat.pi / 180
        let start = 270 *  CGFloat.pi / 180
        let offset = CircleProgressionView.offset

        progressionPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                radius: (self.frame.size.height - offset - circleProgressLayer.lineWidth / 2) / 2,
                startAngle: start,
                endAngle: rad,
                clockwise: true)
    }

    func observe(change: CircleProgressionViewAnimationState) {
        print(change)
        switch change {
        case .firstAnimation:
             fullAnimate { self.state = .secondAnimation }
            break
       case .secondAnimation:
             emptyAnimate { self.state = .firstAnimation }
            break
        case .start, .progress, .stop: break
        }
    }

    func animate(loop: Bool) {

        var completion : ()->Void = {}
        if loop {
            state = .start
            completion = { self.state = .secondAnimation }
        }
        fullAnimate(completion: completion)
    }



    func fullAnimate(completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
        self.state = .progress
        circleProgressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        circleProgressLayer.path
        CATransaction.begin()
         circleProgressLayer.path = progressionPath?.cgPath
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ completion() }
        let animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.strokeEnd))

        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0

        animation.duration = 2

       animation.timingFunction =  CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
            CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)

        circleProgressLayer.add(animation, forKey: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.strokeEnd))
        CATransaction.commit()


    }

    func emptyAnimate(completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
        self.state = .progress
        circleProgressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        CATransaction.begin()

        circleProgressLayer.path = progressionPath?.reversing().cgPath
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ completion() }
        let animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.strokeEnd))

        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = 0.0

        animation.duration = 2
        animation.timingFunction =  CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
            CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)

        circleProgressLayer.add(animation, forKey: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.strokeEnd))
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}

var container : UIView = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
    let view = UIView(frame: frame)
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    return view
}()

let circle = CircleProgressionView(frame: container.frame)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container
circle.setProgressionPath(100)
container.addSubview(circle)
circle.animate(loop: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the empty animation block add the following two lines and you can figure out the reason easily.

```
   func emptyAnimate(completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
    self.state = .progress
    circleProgressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    CATransaction.begin()

  . .....
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
   animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

 ......

  }
```